# c# for loop syntax query - why does this compile

Tags: c#, for-loop

Yesterday while debugging some code I eventually found the culprit line:

```
 for (int i=0; i <- b; i++)
```

instead of:

```
 for (int i=0; i <= b; i++)
```

Why does this compile?
I could understand if it had been mistyped as:

```
for (int i=0; i <-b; i++)
```

Comment: the space inbetween doesn't really matter at all in this case. for the compiler, options 1 and 3 are the same. technically, you can eliminate all spaces in these lines except the one between `int` and `i`.

Comment: Because the compiler allows us to put an operator before a numeric type variable.

Comment: So many answers to say that `i <- b` equals `i < (-b)`. Is `5 < -10` ? No. But `5 < -(-10)` ? Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explaining the more abstract form, in cSharp there is no token '<-', but two tokens '<' and '-'.

When the lexical analyzer reads the characters it checks if the next character produces any tokens that it can recognize (look-ahead). If not, it passes to the parser the last token that it was able to identify and proceeds to the next token identification.

Step by step:

- `<` -> Token identified. Wait for the next entry (look-ahead)
- `<-` -> Unidentified token, pass `<` to the parser and keep the `-`
- `-` -> Token identified. Wait for the next entry (look-ahead)
- `-b` -> Unidentified token, pass `-` to the parser and keep the `b`
- `b` -> Token identified. Wait for the next entry (look-ahead)
- `b;` -> Unidentified token, pass `b` to the parser and keep the`;`
- And so on...

In the end the parser translates this as "i < (-b)".

Obviously it has a deeper and more detailed explanation of how the lexical analyzer and the parser work, but I think it is not necessary to explain to answer your question.

In the summary, it makes no difference whether the code was written as "i <- b" or "i <-b" or "i < - b", because for the lexical analyzer of cSharp, space does not matter "i<-B".

References:

- https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-tokens-identifiers-keywords/
- https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

It compiles because it is syntactically correct. It means `i < (b*-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not. Have a look at this snippet:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program{
    public static void Main(){
        int i=0, j=-5;
        for(;i<-j;i++)
            Console.WriteLine("i: {0}, j: {1}", i, j);
    }
}
```

The end result would be:

```
i: 0, j: -5                                                                                                                 
i: 1, j: -5                                                                                                                 
i: 2, j: -5                                                                                                                 
i: 3, j: -5                                                                                                                 
i: 4, j: -5
```

Its simple math. -(-) is +. So -(j) = -(-5) = 5.

Comment: I would say your code snippet is not written in `C#`

Comment: But you also know here there is no diffrence in many languages c, c#, java, php ... and the other c-based languages.

Comment: Still your answer does not address OP's question "why does this compile". Moreover it claims for some reason that "It is not".

Comment: Its really ridiculous. My code is totally right :(
Who in this world know C# and not understand C????

Comment: I think you are missing a point here. Please reread the question. I would say that OP found a typo (`<=` -> `<-`) which lead to a bug in the code and is wondering why compiler has not helped to prevent it.

Comment: I told him that it isn't a bug. Probably b would be a negative integer. I explained it by writing full code with end result. I think my example is easiest among all of the answers here along with mathematical explanation.

Comment: I would say that we should leave OP to decide what is a bug in OP's code base. But maybe you are right and OP does not know.

Comment: Thanks all. I can see exactly why it can be technically correct but a nasty trap for hitting the wrong key, and difficult to see when ones eyesight is not 20:20. P.S. b would never be a -ve value.

Comment: @gpl: why don't you just make your code `C#`? ... A simple 2nd look at the loop and replacing `printf` will do the trick. Here, try this to get rid of the errrors: https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: @Stefan is it OK now??? I just used C beacause it is the most basic language which every one understand and those constructs are so common in all C-based languages

Comment: @gpl: yes, better. I understand you used `c`, but do note; this community already protests when `c` is marked as `c++`

Answer (score 0):

White space does not define scope in C#, so your statement compiles.

```cs
for 
(
            int 
i
=
        0; 
i 
            <    -

             b
                                 ;
              i
                ++
)
```

would compile too, but you'd be a monster if you let it. The unary `-` operator, like any other, doesn't necessarily need to be next to its operand to be valid.

Comment: @Stefan I'm aware. I answered why - because it's not an error according to the compiler, because the compiler does not consider white space when parsing the statement. The OP assumes that the negation operator must not have white space before its operand, as evidenced by the "I could understand if it had been typed as..." follow on, which is incorrect.

Comment: ... hmm, I think you are right. Although: you really put the focus on the white space - without the `-`, it's confusing, sorry.